# Conditionally splitting string into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a small piece of code that needs to split a string into a javascript object.

The resulting object need to look something like this:

```
var myObject = {
valueOne: value,
valueTwo: value,
arrayOfValues: [values] 
}
```

The strings that need to be converted come in two different formats. Those formats look like:

1) `"MyValues are ('1','2','3')"`
--this would be translated into :

```
var myObject = {
valueOne: myValues,
valueTwo: are,
arrayOfValues: [1,2,3] 
}
```

or
2) `"MyValue="1""`
--this would be translated into :

```
var myObject = {
valueOne: myValue,
valueTwo: =,
arrayOfValues: [1] 
}
```

I know I can split this string like so:

```
var arr[] = myString.split(" ");
```

But deciding which splitter to use based on the makeup of the string, then converting it into a javascript object is a world unknown to me.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT --** I made a small mistake with example number **two**

I updated it so that it's correct. -- The string I'm receiving is in the format of:

```
`"MyValue="1""`
```

samy-delux, thanks for your help! That works great, but the change to this second string breaks your example. (I'm sorry, I mistyped the format of the string.)

I'm doing my best to learn about regular expressions. But don't know enough yet to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go ( http://jsfiddle.net/VBmb8/ ):

```
function parse(str) {
    var match = str.match(/(\w+)\s?([\w=]+)\s?\('(.+)'\)/);

    return {
        valueOne: match[1],
        valueTwo: match[2],
        arrayOfValues: match[3].split("','")
    };
}
```

*** After your edit ***

http://jsfiddle.net/VBmb8/2/

```
function parse(str) {
    var match = str.match(/(\w+)\s?([\w=]+)\s?\(?['"](.+)['"]\)?/);

    return {
        valueOne: match[1],
        valueTwo: match[2],
        arrayOfValues: match[3].split("','")
    };
}
```

Comment: This works great! -- However, I made a mistake in the way string 2 was being loaded into the function.

This change causes the parse function above to no longer work. -- my mistake.

Comment: I've adapted my post to your edits, hope this works for you now!